# discord.py Multiple Countdown Timer

Tags: python, discord.py

I was able to make a countdown timer that edits itself. However When I do multiple timers, one of the timer will either lag, or they all break.

How do i make it so that when someone starts a timer, that timer will start working on its own and any other action won't affect that timer. This way multiple timers can be made.

To start a timer I would just type //timer (time)

```
import discord
import os
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():    #Print when The Code Has connected to Discord
  print("{0.user} Has Connected To Discord".format(client))



@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  Days = 0
  Hours = 0
  Minutes = 0
  Seconds = 0
  ClockH = "00"
  ClockM = "00"
  ClockS = "00"
  
  
  if message.author == client.user:
    if ("⌛COUNTDOWN⌛") in message.content:
      timer = message.content.split()
      timer = list(map(int,timer[1:]))
      Days = timer[0]
      Hours = timer[1]
      Minutes = timer[2]
      Seconds = timer[3]
      Finish = False
      while Finish == False:
        if Hours <10: ClockH = "0"+str(Hours)
        else: ClockH = str(Hours)
        if Minutes <10: ClockM = "0"+str(Minutes)
        else: ClockM = str(Minutes)
        if Seconds <10: ClockS = "0"+str(Seconds)
        else: ClockS = str(Seconds)
        
        if Days == 0:
          await message.edit(content="{}:{}:{}".format(ClockH,ClockM,ClockS))  
        else:
          await message.edit(content="{} Days | {}:{}:{}".format(Days,ClockH,ClockM,ClockS))


        if Minutes>0:
          if Seconds>0: Seconds-=1
          else: 
            Minutes-=1
            Seconds = 59
        elif Seconds>0:
          Seconds-=1
        else: Finish = True
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
      
    return
    
  if "//timer" in message.content:
    timer = message.content.split()

    countdown = []
    timer = timer[1:]        
    for i in range(len(timer)):
      if ("day" in timer[i].lower()):
        Days = int(timer[i-1])
      if ("hour" in timer[i].lower()) or ("hr" in timer[i].lower()):
        Hours = int(timer[i-1])
      if "min" in timer[i].lower():
        Minutes = timer[i-1]
      if "sec" in timer[i].lower():
        Seconds = int(timer[i-1])
      
      if ":" in timer[i]:
        timer = timer[i]
        index = 0
        
        for i in range(3):
          if ":" in timer:
            index = timer.find(":")
            if len(timer[:index]) <= 2:
              countdown.append(int(timer[:index]))
              timer = timer[index+1:]
            else:  
              Error = "Please Retype Timer"
          else: countdown.append(int(timer))
        Hours,Minutes,Seconds = countdown
    await message.channel.send("⌛COUNTDOWN⌛ {} {} {} {}".format(Days,Hours,Minutes,Seconds))
    print(Days, Hours,Minutes,Seconds)
        
    
    

    

    
client.run(os.environ['Token'])
```

Comment: Would Recursion work for this? if so, how would I do it? because I tried but i keep getting errors

Answer (score 0):

It's no longer necessary to edit the timestamp messages yourself, and it's very likely to be considered API abuse when you do this - bots are not supposed to do x action every y time.

Instead, you can use [discord's own timer](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#message-formatting-timestamp-styles) in your messages. To use a timer, you simply put `<t:12345:R>` with a number there that represents the timestamp. It also looks nicer and can show detailed information when you hover over it.

```py
@client.command()
async def countdown(ctx, hour: int, minute: int, second: int):
    total_time = 3600*hour + 60*minute + second
    timestamp = int(time.time()) + total_time
    await ctx.send(f'<t:{timestamp}:R>')
```

(To do this without using commands, change `ctx.send` to `message.channel.send`, and use your own definition of the total time in seconds.)

---

Output:

[image]

[image]